# Do luxury booster from the same resource stack?

Tags: endless-legend

When I have enough units of a luxury resource to activate the booster twice, the game allows me to do that. Do I get double the effect of the booster or will one activation go to waste?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't get double the effect, but the duration is extended. E.g. if you use a boost and the effect lasts 20 turns, then you immediately use it again, it lasts 40 turns. So, the activation will not go to waste.

This is especially useful, if you have any temporary modifiers to increase the duration of a boost. E.g. in one game I had an effect ( either through tech or a great building), which increased the duration of boosters, depending on how many boosters I have active. This allowed me to get up to 36 turns of boost per activation. So, i could quickly stack up the booster duration to triple digit turns with a low resource cost.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess I should have done some more testing. Thanks for the clarification, I'm deleting my own answer. :)

Comment: The bonus you're talking about is a special technology available only to the Allayi faction called "Luxury Alchemists," which increases the duration granted from using a booster by 20% for every other active luxury booster. It even works on food/industry/science stockpile boosters! If you have 5 luxury boosters active, giving you +100% increased duration, the stockpile boost will last two turns instead of one, with further jumps at 10 and 15 boosters. A late game Allayi with access to the Market is unstoppable.